# How to partition a table by timestamp, where data from every i'th day goes to partition i?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I'm looking into partitioning a table in my InnoDB database.  I have a column corresponding to a UTC timestamp, and I want to partition around that.

The basic idea that I want to capture is a partitioning scheme where, with a fixed number of partitions, we cycle through them as follows:

Given 3 partitions (3 for simplicity)

> - Data with timestamp column from day 1 goes into partition 1
> - Data with timestamp column from day 2 goes into partition 2
> - Data with timestamp column from day 3 goes into partition 3
> - Data with timestamp column from day 4 goes into partition 1
> - ..... day 5 .... partition 2
> - ... rinse and repeat

Basically, extract the day out of the timestamp and put the row into partition `DAY MOD N` where `DAY` is the day that the timestamp corresponds to (filtering out hours/minutes/seconds) and `N` is the number of partitions.

This is probably easily done, but I can't find a similar example to emulate this with.  What would the `ALTER TABLE` query be to partition in this fashion?

**Update**

By atxdba's suggestion, I tried partitioning by hash.  I tried the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE table_to_partition PARTITION BY HASH(DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(my_timestamp))) partitions 8;
```

This results in error code 1564: `This partition function is not allowed.`  Looking at [this list of limitations for partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html), it doesn't appear that FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP is supported for partioning a table, so a different transformation from timestamp to date is required.

Comment: You will not get any performance benefit from doing such.  Nor any other benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use FROM_UNIXTIME() because hash partitions must be based on an integer expression.  But assuming your timestamp is stored as an integer, you can use `DIV` to return an integer.

Here's a demo of partitioning in the way you describe:

```
mysql> create table table_to_partition (
  my_timestamp int unsigned primary key
) partition by hash(my_timestamp DIV (60*60*24)) partitions 3;

mysql> insert into table_to_partition values (unix_timestamp(now()));
mysql> insert into table_to_partition values (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 1 day));
mysql> insert into table_to_partition values (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 2 day));
mysql> insert into table_to_partition values (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 3 day));
mysql> insert into table_to_partition values (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 4 day));
mysql> insert into table_to_partition values (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 5 day));

mysql> select table_name, partition_name, table_rows 
from information_schema.partitions where table_name='table_to_partition';

+--------------------+----------------+------------+
| table_name         | partition_name | table_rows |
+--------------------+----------------+------------+
| table_to_partition | p0             |          2 |
| table_to_partition | p1             |          2 |
| table_to_partition | p2             |          2 |
+--------------------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: That's a good workaround.  I was trying something like that out using "/" instead of the DIV keyword and having no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: Right, because the "/" division operator returns a float, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [hash partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-hash.html).  You just define how many "buckets" you want and a column to hash by, mysql takes care of distributing the rows for you.

Comment: I looked into that, but that looks like it will just take the mod of the value (which as a unix timestamp, isn't super useful since data will not be contiguous by day).  Is there something smarter that MySQL does to handle that scenario?

Comment: I thought about your suggestion for hash partitioning, and tried the following: `ALTER TABLE table_to_partition PARTITION BY HASH(DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(my_timestamp))) partitions 8;`.  This didn't work though, with the error message: Error Code 1564: This partition function is not allowed

Comment: An alternative to ensure date distribution is to use Range partitioning - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html.  The caveat with this approach is mysql will not auto extend for you so you need a maintenance script to maintain adding new partitions as time goes on.

Comment: There are two problems... `FROM_UNIXTIME()` takes an integer as an argument, and returns a `DATETIME` value... so a `TIMESTAMP` column wouldn't be valid input for that function... `PARTITION BY HASH(DAYOFMONTH(my_timestamp)) ...` would have been the more correct expression, but that's not valid for a different reason: `ERROR 1486 (HY000): Constant, random or timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed`.

Answer (score 0):

quasi-related: remember if you have an auto incrementing column in a partitioned table, it will act different depending on the table type:

MyISAM: the auto inc. column will increment for each partition

InnoDB: the auto inc. column will be unique in the table.